# Hibernate, Postresql. Exception "Could not instantiate persister org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister"

Tags: java, hibernate

I have got hibernate 4.1.5.SP1 and PostreSQL 9.1.

This is log:

```
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate persister org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:22)
    at Dao.VideoDao.getAllVideos(VideoDao.java:96)
    at Dao.Main.main(Main.java:17)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate persister org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:174)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:381)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1744)
    at util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:18)
```

This is hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mybase</property>
<property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
<property name="connection.password">******</property>
<property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>

<mapping resource="Video.hbm.xml"/>
```

This is Video.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="logic.Video" table="video">
    <id column="id" name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
      <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>
    <property column="description" name="description" type="java.lang.String"/>

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

This is HibernateUtil.java

```
package util;

import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

public class HibernateUtil {
  private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
  private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

    static {
      try {

            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure();//("D:\\java\\workspace\\hibernate3\\bin\\hibernate.cfg.xml");
            serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();        
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

      } catch (Throwable ex) {
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
      }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
      return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

This is Video.java

```
package Logic;

public class Video {
    private Long id;
    private String description;

    public Video(){}

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

This is IVideoDao.java

```
package Dao;

import Logic.Video;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public interface IVideoDao {
      public void addVideo(Video video) throws SQLException;
      public void updateVideo(Long id, Video video) throws SQLException;
      public Video getVideoById(Long id) throws SQLException;
      public Collection<Video> getAllVideos() throws SQLException;
      public void deleteVideo(Video video) throws SQLException;
      public Collection<Video> getParamVideos(Long start, Long finish) throws SQLException;
}
```

This is VideoDao.java

```
package Dao;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;

import util.HibernateUtil;

import Logic.Video;

public class VideoDao implements IVideoDao 
{

    @Override
    public void addVideo(Video video) throws SQLException 
    {
        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(video);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "Error 'addVideo'", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
        } 
        finally 
        {
            if (session != null && session.isOpen()) 
            {
                session.close();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void updateVideo(Long id, Video video) throws SQLException 
    {
        Session session = null;
        try 
        {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.update(video);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "Error 'updateVideo'", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
        } finally {
            if (session != null && session.isOpen()) 
            {
                session.close();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Video getVideoById(Long id) throws SQLException 
    {
        Session session = null;
        Video video = null;
        try 
        {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            video = (Video) session.load(Video.class, id);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "Error 'findById'", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
        } 
        finally 
        {
            if (session != null && session.isOpen()) 
            {
                session.close();
            }
        }
        return video;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<Video> getAllVideos() throws SQLException 
    {
        Session session = null;
        List<Video> videos = new ArrayList<Video>();
        try 
        {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            videos = session.createCriteria(Video.class).list();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "Error 'getAll'", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
        } 
        finally 
        {
            if (session != null && session.isOpen()) 
            {
                session.close();
            }
        }
        return videos;
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteVideo(Video video) throws SQLException 
    {
        Session session = null;
        try 
        {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.delete(video);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "Error 'deleteVideo'", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
        } 
        finally 
        {
            if (session != null && session.isOpen()) 
            {
                session.close();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<Video> getParamVideos(Long start, Long finish) throws SQLException 
    {
        Session session = null;
        List<Video> videos = new ArrayList<Video>();
        try {
          session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
          session.beginTransaction();
          Query query = session.createQuery(
              " select v "
                  + " from video v "
                  + " where id between :startId and :finishId "
          )
            .setLong("startId", start)
            .setLong("finishId", finish);
          videos = (List<Video>) query.list();
          session.getTransaction().commit();

        } 
        finally 
        {
            if (session != null && session.isOpen()) 
            {
                session.close();
            }
        }
        return videos;
    }

}
```

This is Factory.java

```
package Dao;

public class Factory {

    private static VideoDao videoDao = null;
    private static Factory instance = null;

    public static synchronized Factory getInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = new Factory();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private Factory(){}

    public IVideoDao getVideoDao()
    {
        if (videoDao == null)
        {
            videoDao = new VideoDao();
        }
        return videoDao;
    }
}
```

This is Main.java

```
package Dao;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;

import Logic.Video;

public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws SQLException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

        Collection<Video> videos = Factory.getInstance().getVideoDao().getAllVideos();
        Iterator<Video> iterator = videos.iterator();

        System.out.println("========All films=========");
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
          Video video = iterator.next();
          System.out.println(video.getId().toString() + ") Video: " + video.getDescription());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104221/hibernate-buildsessionfactory-exception

Comment: Can you provide complete stack trace.. Seems the provided one is not complete.